# Trace logging settings for Liberty on Bluemix

Tags: logging, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I'm able to change trace levels for Liberty via the Bluemix UI but the settings don't seem to persist across restarts. Is this expected/by-design? If so, this would make debugging your application startup much harder.

I could change the log levels within server.xml but because I'm using Cloud Foundry, that's a lot of work to just change a single setting that already has a UI

Comment: Has this changed at all with diego enabled apps? I used ssh and vi to edit both server.xml and server.xml.org, restarted and the changes were lost. Specifically I'm trying to find an easy way to change **persisted** log levels between restarts. Pushing files to change log levels is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the server.xml as part of your app push command so it will persist between restarts. When you restart a runtime, a new buildpack is created and started. Its behaviour at starting is modified by your server.xml or any supported environment variable (but I am not aware of any for tracing).

Check how to push server.xml as part of your app here: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/liberty/optionsForPushing.html

Answer (score 1):

you should set the trace level in **server.xml**

enable tracing on the server side by adding this to your server.xml:

```
<logging traceSpecification="com.ibm.ws.jmx.*=all"/>
```

Then you have to push your server package:

1) Create a directory that is named defaultServer. 
2) Create an apps directory in the defaultServer directory. 
3) Copy your WAR or EAR file into the defaultServer/apps directory. 
4) In the defaultServer directory, create your own server.xml file

After the server directory is ready, you can deploy it to Bluemix.

```
$ cf push <yourappname> -p defaultServer
```

You can also push a packaged server file to Bluemix. The packaged server file is created by using Liberty's server package command.

as mentioned by Jose Miguel you can find more information here: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html#optionsforpushinglibertyapplications

Comment: We have defaults set in server.xml and we do push this as part of our app (via CF) but if we're trying to debug a specific problem, I don't want to have to re-push just to change the log levels (and then push again to change it back). Using the trace screens works fine to change the logging level but not if I'm trying to debug a problem during our startup. 

It doesn't make sense that this nice ui is provided but does not persist the levels. I definitely understand that this would not persist across a re-stage but I do expect it to persist if I simply stop/start the server.